# Deploying .NET Application

Tags: .net, deployment, server, publish

I've just started working on .NET. I'm a coldfusion developer, so I'm used to just upload all the files to the server by FTP.
I tried to do the same with .NET and create a very basic website saying Hello World. It runs well in my localhost.

Using Visual Studio I go to:

```
Build -> Publish Project -> File System Method
```

Then I saved the files in my local computer.

Using FileZilla I transferred the files to the server. The problem is when I run the server, it only displays the folders files and directories. Not the website.

Does anyone know what should I do?

I could deploy MVC website using FTP in Visual Studio. The problem now id when I run the website URL is shows:

```
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
    Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you need to properly configure your website in IIS. Without details of your site , nobody will be able to do other, but speculation.

Make sure your site has the proper file configured as the default document e.g. index.html, default.html, index.asp, etc.

[image]

Comment: How can I configure the IIS? Could you tell me how I can set the Index.cshtml as the default? It's a MVC project

Comment: @user6824563 added a picture

Comment: Thank you... Does it apply for a MVC application? If so, what is the default document in a MVC application?

Comment: more likely (not necessarily) in a default VS project ASP.NET MVC application it will be Index.cshtml

Comment: it does not really matter what it is, it can be any file, this setting is usually the home page for the occasions when a visitor does not specify a page in the URL.

Comment: That what I think. When I run the application in the localhost it load the page (I think the index.cshtml in the Home Controller), but when I run it on the server I got the A default document is not configured for the requested URL

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Publishing Tools Provide several ways to deploy. Since you already have used FTP in the past, you may continue to use that option and deploy through FTP directly to the server.

Build -> Publish

Now choose FTP (or SFTP) and configure the HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD and any other options you want to use.

It may be helpful to try it this way once so that you can see what files Visual Studio copies to the server. It will also eliminate any manual user errors you may have unintentionally caused during the file copy so you can determine if it's a server configuration problem rather than a code deployment problem.

Comment: I tried to do it but I got the error: Cannot create folder http://myserver.com/dotNet  I already have this folder on my server